# Convert to Different number to Decimals C# (scientific notation to decimal)

Tags: c#

I was trying to convert following figure in to decimals but its throwing a error. could you please tell me how to change the format

`8.37E-08-05`(scientific notation)   ====> `0.00000008372014000000`

```
var convertDecimal = Convert.ToDecimal("8.37E-08");
```

Error: 
Input string was not in a correct format.

Comment: What code have you tried?

Comment: How were you "trying to convert"?

Comment: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dwhawy9k(v=vs.110).aspx

Comment: You should show the code you have tried and also give us the exact error message.

Comment: The error message is exactly right. "8.37E-08-05" is not a valid number.

Comment: Yes. I know its not a number asking how to change the format?

Comment: What @ChristianHayter is saying is that the `-05` at the end of the string is not a valid part of scientific notation. The string is valid for `8.37E-08`, but once the `-05` is encountered, the string is invalid.

Comment: Thanks Cole I edited, that's my mistake

Answer (score 2):

first the string format should be something like `8.37E-08` and not `8.37E-08-05`.
it's a floating point number. you have to convert it as below

```
 decimal d = decimal.Parse("8.37E-08", System.Globalization.NumberStyles.Float);
```

Answer (score 1):

Thanks Sam

I use the same approach

```
 decimal convertDecimal = Decimal.Parse("8.37E-08", NumberStyles.AllowExponent | NumberStyles.AllowDecimalPoint);
```